# Node.js Chaining promises using q.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, q

I am using node.js with mongodb and q.js for promises.

Following is my mongodb schema :

```
{
  UserId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  FirstName: String,
  LastName: String,
  Gender: String,
  userDocument: [userDocumentSchema],
  userEducation: [userEducationDetailsSchema]
};
var userEducationDetailsSchema = new Schema({
  DegreeName: String,
  University: String,
});
var userDocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  DocumentName: String,
  DocumentPath: String
});


I have following function by chaining promises:

var updateUserDetails = function (req, res) {
  var finalResult = [];
  /* This is the function to update user using promise.*/
  updateUserBasicDetails(req).then(function (req) {
    _.each(req.body.userEducation, function (sd) {
      return getEducationDetail(req.body._id, sd) /* this fun finds if education details are present or not by iterating usertEducation Array */
        .then(function (result) {
          if (result) {
            /* if education details exist then this will update the details */
            return updateEducationDetails(sd, req.body._id).then(
              function (result) {
                return result;
              })
          } else {
            /*else add the education details*/
            return addEducationDetails(sd, req.body._id).then(
              function (result) {
                return result;
              })
          }
        }).then(function (result) {
          finalResult.push(result);
        })
    })
    return JSON.stringify(finalResult);
  }).then(function (finalResult) {
    res.json({
      "token": finalResult /*but here m getting empty result */
    })
  }).catch(console.log).done();
}
```

My query is :

1. Is this the right way to implement chainging of promises ?
2. In last chain of then I am getting empty result but when i print the o/p to console i get right result.
3. The way i have done iteration of getEducationDetail function , is it right way or is there any alternative. if so how can i achieve the same.

Comment: You are returning `finalResult` synchronously, but the values are populated only asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

you code can be cleaner, please adjust some parts like this

```
var updateUserDetails = function (req, res) {
  var finalResult = [];
  /* This is the function to update user using promise.*/
  return updateUserBasicDetails(req)
    .then(function (req) {
      _.each(req.body.userEducation, function (sd) {
        return getEducationDetail(req.body._id, sd)
          .then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
              return updateEducationDetails(sd, req.body._id)
            } 
            else {
              return addEducationDetails(sd, req.body._id)
            }
          })
          .then(function (result) {
            return result;
          })
          .then(function (result) {
            finalResult.push(result);
          })
        })

      return JSON.stringify(finalResult);
    })
    .then(function (finalResult) {
      res.json({
        "token": finalResult /*but here m getting empty result */
      })
    })
    .catch(function (e) { console.log(e); })
    .done();
}
```

and the above code can be also cleaner, if you replace `_.each` and use `q.all` instead.

- note: you are using javascript es5 that make your code quite long, you can shorten it using javascript es6 and use arrow function instead of `function(x, y) {}`